# Extracting the component distribution parameters from a mixed-normal distribution (for n > 2 normal)

Tags: distributions, parameters

I'm trying to extract the distribution parameters of the sub-distributions which comprise a mixed normal distribution.

I'll give my attempts so far.

First the simulated data:

```
MixedGaussiaData = Apply[Join, {RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 2], 300], RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.7], 500], RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.4], 500], RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200]}];
```

Which when plotted looks like this:

[image]

So we have four normal distributions with different $\sigma$ values and different number of points, but all distributions have a common mean value $\mu = 0$.

I define my $n$ mixed-normal distribution as:

```
NMixedGaussian[n_] := MixtureDistribution[Array[w, n], MapThread[NormalDistribution[#1, #2] &, {Array[m, n], Array[s, n]}]]
```

Then using `FindDistributionParameters`

```
FourMixedNormalMLE = FindDistributionParameters[MixedGaussiaData, NMixedGaussian[4], ParameterEstimator->{"MaximumLikelihood", PrecisionGoal->1, AccuracyGoal->1}]
```

If I plot the result, it looks pretty good:

[image]

However if we take a look at the results, they're not that good when compared to the inputs of the simulation:

```
mMLE = Array[m, 4] /. FourMixedNormalMLE
sMLE = Array[s, 4] /. FourMixedNormalMLE
wMLE = Array[w, 4] /. FourMixedNormalMLE

{0.0284676, 0.00902554, 0.0930328, -0.470579}
{1.8648, 0.274301, 0.667947, 0.385259}
{0.237727, 0.192302, 0.475281, 0.0946906}
```

---

**Second attempt:**

I tried explicitly defining the Mixed-Gaussain function with `ProbabilityDensity`:

```
Clear[w, m, s, n];
NMixedGaussian[n_] := MixtureDistribution[Array[w, n], MapThread[NormalDistribution[#1, #2] &, {Array[m, n], Array[s, n]}]]

NMixGauss = NMixedGaussian[4];
NMixGaussPDF[z_] = FullSimplify[PDF[NMixGauss, z], DistributionParameterAssumptions[NMixGauss]]

NMixGaussPD = ProbabilityDistribution[NMixGaussPDF[z], {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> DistributionParameterAssumptions[NMixGauss]]

FourMixedNormalPDFMLE = FindDistributionParameters[MixedGaussiaData, NMixGaussPD, ParameterEstimator->{"MaximumLikelihood", PrecisionGoal->1, AccuracyGoal->1}]
```

This makes it worse. I think the main issue might be initial values and constraints, but I'm not sure how to best implement this. Does anyone have any suggestions?

One thing I noticed is that the weights produced by `FindDistributionParameters` don't seem to make sense. They sum to one, but none seem to correspond to weights defined by $1/\sigma^{2}$ or $1/\sigma_{\rm{SE}}^{2}$

---

Addition:
What I'm trying to achieve is another way of performing a weighted mean. I could divide the simulated data up into chunks/bins, find the $\mu$ and $\sigma$ for each one and perform a weighted mean. I want to avoid binning if possible, hence this approach.

Just to be a bit more explicit in what I am trying to do/expect to see. Here I've just performed a simple weighted average and determined the associated standard error:

```
SeedRandom[1]

Gaussian1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 2], 300];
Gaussian2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.7], 500];
Gaussian3 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.4], 500];
Gaussian4 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200];

M = {Mean[Gaussian1], Mean[Gaussian2], Mean[Gaussian3], Mean[Gaussian4]};
S = {StandardDeviation[Gaussian1], StandardDeviation[Gaussian2], StandardDeviation[Gaussian3], StandardDeviation[Gaussian4]};
SE = {StandardDeviation[Gaussian1]/Sqrt[Length[Gaussian1]], StandardDeviation[Gaussian2]/Sqrt[Length[Gaussian2]], StandardDeviation[Gaussian3]/Sqrt[Length[Gaussian3]], StandardDeviation[Gaussian4]/Sqrt[Length[Gaussian4]]};
W = 1 / SE^2;

Around[WU = Total[W M]/Total[W], WSE = Sqrt[(Total[W M^2]/Total[W] - (Total[W M]/Total[W])^2 Length[W]/(Length[W] - 1))  / Length[W]]]

OUT = Around[-0.010808335694884515`, 0.0184845352965455]


mMLE = Array[m, 4] /. FourMixedNormalMLE
sMLE = Array[s, 4] /. FourMixedNormalMLE
wMLE = Array[w, 4] /. FourMixedNormalMLE

Around[WUMLE = Total[wMLE mMLE], WSEMLE = Sqrt[(Total[wMLE mMLE^2] - (Total[wMLE mMLE])^2 Length[wMLE]/(Length[wMLE] - 1))  / Length[wMLE]]]

OUT = Around[0.008160465141904528, 0.07937540663098669]
```

If I compare the results from those determined from a weighted mean, to those I get from `FindDistributionParameters` they are quite different.

Comment: Are you aware of `SmoothKernelDistribution` ? It sounds like a non-parametric method like this would be more useful to you than a large number of weighted gaussians and 3N parameters.

Comment: I've seen it in the context of plotting a distribution, but not for producing a weighted mean. Would you be willing to show me an example?

Comment: Something like: `skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[data];
{weights, means, bandwidth} = skd[[2]];
Show[Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"], 
 Plot[PDF[skd, x], {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Thick]]` then you have `Mean[WeightedData[means, weights]]` which coincides with `Mean[data]` anyway. Also it has an option like `MaxMixtureKernels -> 50` so you can limit the number of mixture distributions, but don't set this too low or it starts to misrepresent the data.

Comment: Ah, that's not what I'm after, but neat that one can do that. Thnaks.

Comment: A minor point:  your data is not from a mixture distribution in the sense that while the weights are constant, the actual realization of counts from each subpopulation is not.  To get a sample from the mixture distribution you're trying to fit consider: `parms = {Thread[Array[w, 4] -> {300, 500, 500, 200}], Thread[Array[m, 4] -> {0, 0, 0, 0}], Thread[Array[s, 4] -> {2, 0.7, 0.4, 1}]} // Flatten; data = RandomVariate[NMixedGaussian[4] /. parms, 1500]`.

Comment: "One thing I noticed is that the weights produced by FindDistributionParameters don't seem to make sense. They sum to one, but none seem to correspond to weights 1/sigma^2" I don't understand this remark. Why should the weights have anything to do with the standard deviation?

Comment: @SjoerdSmit The weights of a mixture distribution are by definition non-negative and sum to 1.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Sorry.  For some reason the double quotes escaped me.  I gotta learn how to read better.

Comment: Note that there's no reason to expect that the order in which you constructed the data will necessarily match to the order in which the estimates of the parameters are returned.

Comment: @JimB I didn't think the order of points in a mixed distribution mattered? So I figured that while a mixture distribution in the conventional sense wouldn't have this ordering, if you consider the data as a whole it would still be the same. If I run your code, I get an identical looking distribution.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit A fair comment. I suppose I was thinking in the context of a weighted avereage. Usually one defines the weights inverse squares of the variance or standard-error. But I suppose you may define weights in any number of ways.

Comment: It's the collection of the 4 triplets of parameters that matter but the 4 triplets returned might occur in any order.  I'm not talking about the order of the data points. I'm writing up an answer as we speak.

Comment: Okay, that's quite important point. However I still get parameters that are quite different to the input parameters. I'll add a bit more to my question to illustrate what I am expecting to see.

Comment: @JimB I've made an addition, which hopefully explains what I am trying to do/expect to see.

Comment: Your estimates of the weights and standard deviations would match better if there was much more separation between the distributions.  In other words, the non-intuitive results are in part from all of the means being equal and not lots of difference among the standard deviations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a discussion and we came to the conclusion (I think) that what was needed was a "mixed model" rather than a "mixture model".  A simplified definition of a mixed model is a regression with more than one error term (resulting in some observations being correlated with other observations).  *Mathematica* does not currently offer a direct way to analyze mixed models but certainly has the basic tools to do so.

For this particular question the mixed model can written as follows:

$$y_{ij}=\mu+\gamma_i+\epsilon_{ij}$$

where $y_{ij}$ is the $j$-th observation of subpopulation $i$, $\mu$ is the overall mean, $\gamma_i \sim N(0,\sigma_P^2)$ is a random effect of subpopulation $i$, and $\epsilon_{ij} \sim N(0,\sigma_i^2)$ is the measurement error for each of the $n_i$ observations from subpopulation $i$.  All random variables are assumed to be independent of each other.

The objective is to estimate $\mu$ (and get an appropriate measure of precision).

First, generate some data in *Mathematica*.

```
μ = 2 ;(* Overall mean *)
σPop = 0.1; (* Standard deviation of subpopulation deviations from μ *)

σ = {0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.7, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2}; (* Subpopulation standard deviations *)
n = {100, 200, 100, 100, 300, 400, 50, 50, 25, 50}; (* Subpopulation sample sizes *)

(* Subpopulation deviations from μ *)
SeedRandom[12345];
deviations = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, σPop], 10];

(* Put together subpopulation identification and associated observations *)
data = Flatten[Table[Table[{j, μ + deviations[[j]] + 
       RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, σ[[j]]]]},
     {i, n[[j]]}], {j, 10}], 1];
```

A plot of the data and the random deviations for each subpopulation:

```
a = Accumulate[n];
levels = Table[If[i == 1, {{1, μ + deviations[[i]]}, {a[[1]], μ + deviations[[i]]}},
    If[i == 10, {{a[[i - 1]] + 1, μ + deviations[[i]]}, {a[[10]], μ + deviations[[i]]}},
     {{a[[i - 1]] + 1, μ + deviations[[i]]}, {a[[i]], μ + deviations[[i]]}}]], {i, 10}];
Show[ListPlot[data[[All, 2]], Frame -> True], 
 ListPlot[levels, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Data and deviations from mean]

One can use `RLink` to estimate all of the parameters.  For now I just show how to get the estimate of the overall mean (appropriately weighted) and an associated standard error.  First get `RLink` working.

```
Needs["RLink`"]
RLinkResourcesInstall[]
InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "c:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.1"]
```

Now for the analysis with the previously created data.

```
RSet["y", data[[All, 2]]];
RSet["pop", data[[All, 1]]];
result = REvaluate["{
    # Create a data frame with the measurement and associated subpopulation;
    d=data.frame(y=y, pop=factor(pop));
    # Load the nlme library;
    library(nlme);
    # Run analysis;
    results=lme(y ~ 1, data=d, random = ~ 1|pop, 
      weights=varIdent(form=~1|pop),
      control=lmeControl(maxIter = 500, msMaxIter = 500));
    
    # Return the " weighted mean " and a standard error;
    summary(results)$tTable
    }"];
(* Make the result look nice *)
TableForm[result[[1]], TableHeadings -> result[[2, 1, 2]]]
```

[image: Result from fitting a linear mixed model]

If there is variability in the means of the subpopulations, then this technique will generally have a much smaller standard error for the mean than using a standard weighted mean.  The main reason for that is that the standard weighted mean (described by the OP) assumes that the means of the subpopulations are all essentially identical.  When the subpopulation means are not identical, then the precision is adversely affected.

So a "mixture model" is a random mixture of different distributions and you don't know which observation comes from any particular distribution.  But you can still estimate all of the parameters knowing the number (and type) of distributions involved.

A "mixed model" is where you known which subpopulation is associated with each observation and it assumes that the deviation of the subpopulation mean follows a some distribution (usually one assumes normality but that is not required).

Answer (score 1):

While the estimation process will process any dataset and real datasets never really match the what the model expects, the dataset you created isn't a mixture distribution in the usual sense in that you have the counts of each subpopulation fixed.  In a standard mixture distribution, the counts of each subpopulation will vary.

To generate data for your mixture models I recommend something like the following:

```
NMixedGaussian[n_] := MixtureDistribution[Array[w, n], 
  MapThread[NormalDistribution[#1, #2] &, {Array[m, n], Array[s, n]}]]
parms = {Thread[Array[w, 4] -> {300, 500, 500, 200}/1500],
    Thread[Array[m, 4] -> {0, 0, 0, 0}],
    Thread[Array[s, 4] -> {2, 0.7, 0.4, 1}]} // Flatten;
SeedRandom[12345];
data = RandomVariate[NMixedGaussian[4] /. parms, 1500];
```

You used `FindDistributionParameters` which works fine but its drawback is that you just get estimates and no measures of precision or correlation among parameter estimators.  I use `FindDistributionParameters` just to get starting values for a relatively simple set of steps that gets you the measures of precision.  With those measures you can see if the precision levels explain any differences you see from the "true" parameters.  (And it's even more helpful when you just have the data and not the "true" parameters that generated the data.)

Here is a brute force approach:

```
(* FindDistributionParameters *)
FourMixedNormalMLE = FindDistributionParameters[data, NMixedGaussian[4],
  ParameterEstimator -> {"MaximumLikelihood", PrecisionGoal -> 10,
    AccuracyGoal -> 10, MaxIterations -> 5000}]
(* {w[1] -> 0.189239, w[2] -> 0.504157, w[3] -> 0.187723, w[4] -> 0.118881, 
    m[1] -> -0.147546, s[1] -> 2.02087, m[2] -> 0.0856405, s[2] -> 0.40548, 
    m[3] -> 0.437306, s[3] -> 0.856352, m[4] -> -0.794093, s[4] -> 0.463292} *)

(* Maximize log likelihood using the previous solution as starting values *)
logL = LogLikelihood[NMixedGaussian[4] /. w[4] -> 1 - w[1] - w[2] - w[3], data];
mle = FindMaximum[{logL, 
   0 < w[1] < 1 && 0 < w[2] < 1 && 0 < w[3] < 1 && w[1] + w[2] + w[3] < 1
    && s[1] > 0 && s[2] > 0 && s[3] > 0 && s[4] > 0},
  Delete[FourMixedNormalMLE /. Rule -> List, 4]]
(* {-2013.26, {w[1] -> 0.18932, w[2] -> 0.50593, w[3] -> 0.192173, 
  m[1] -> -0.14801, m[2] -> 0.0831314, m[3] -> 0.416784, m[4] -> -0.809995, 
  s[1] -> 2.02032, s[2] -> 0.406299, s[3] -> 0.863456, s[4] -> 0.453506}} *)
    
(* Estimate the covariance and correlation matrices *)
cov = -Inverse[(D[logL, {{w[1], w[2], w[3], m[1], m[2], m[3], m[4], s[1], 
  s[2], s[3], s[4]}, 2}]) /. mle[[2]]];
cor = Table[cov[[i, j]]/Sqrt[cov[[i, i]] cov[[j, j]]], {i, 11}, {j, 11}];

(* Standard errors for parameters *)
stdErr = Sqrt[Diagonal[cov]]
(* {0.0451595, 0.215176, 0.343823, 0.172553, 0.176252, 1.46912, 1.09217, 
     0.161291, 0.0847135, 0.51714, 0.673961} *)
```

So it seems that you want a "parametric" approach to obtain a better estimate the mean of a distribution from a sample knowing that it is a mixture of normals.  However, just using the sample mean and the sample standard error seems a lot simpler and might very well have similar precision.

From the estimated parameters an estimate of the mean is

```
{w[1], w[2], w[3], 1 - w[1] - w[2] - w[3]}.{m[1], m[2], m[3], m[4]} /. mle[[2]]
(* 0.00294456 *)
```

If you just looked at the sample mean:

```
Mean[data]
(* 0.00294456 *)
```

The values are identical.  But I'm likely not understanding your objective.

The "true" mean and standard deviation for your example:

```
#[NMixedGaussian[4] /. parms] & /@ {Mean, StandardDeviation}
(* {0., 1.07238} *)
```

Mean and standard deviation from the data:

```
#[data] & /@ {Mean, StandardDeviation}
(* {0.00294456, 1.06693} *)
```

Mean and standard deviation from the estimated parameters:

```
#[NMixedGaussian[4] /. w[4] -> 1 - w[1] - w[2] - w[3]] /. mle[[2]] & /@ {Mean, StandardDeviation}
(* {0.00294456, 1.06657} *)
```

All match up pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to prepare an answer. My confusion arises in that if I split the data up by distribution, and calculate a weighted mean and standard error I get a different answer and different standard error, if you have a look at my latest edit you can see the difference in values.

Comment: Your `Around` statements have an incorrect formula for the standard deviation because both of those statements don't include appropriate mention of `S` (the standard deviations of the individual data sets).  But if your objective is to look at only the complete data set which does not identify which subpopulation to which a sample belongs, then I don't understand the attempt at using sample estimates of the mean and standard deviations as if the identity of each sample point is know.  Clearly, I'm not understanding your "weighted mean" objective.

Comment: They are included via the weights, I define the weights as $W = 1/(S^{2} / n)$. I think this is correct? ${\rm{Var(x)}} = \frac{n}{n-1}\left(\frac{\sum_i w_{i} x^{2}_{i}}{\sum_{i} w_{i}} - (\bar{x})^{2}\right)$ is the formula I use. Could you show me what you think I should be using?

Comment: I see.  But the second `Around` doesn't include any standard deviations.  And I'll check the formula you just mentioned.

Comment: Just so it's easier this is where I got the formula from: http://seismo.berkeley.edu/~kirchner/Toolkits/Toolkit_12.pdf

Comment: Also here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean#Correcting_for_over-_or_under-dispersion

Comment: I think there are two issues in which I'm not following.  First, there is a difference between a mixture distribution where you don't know which subpopulation from which a sample point is chosen and separate samples of known size from different subpopulations in which you do know the identity of the subpopulation *AND* you believe they share the mean (i.e., they just have difference variances).  Second, there is a difference in the parameters and the sample estimates.  The true standard deviation of a mixture distribution (as you've defined) is...

Comment: $\sigma=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i(\sigma_i^2+\mu_i^2-\mu^2)]}$.  If you have estimates of those parameters, then you'd plug in those estimates (at least that's one way to do it).  The standard error of a mean based on 1,500 samples would be $\sigma/\sqrt{1500}$.

Comment: If you have some time, could we move this to a chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116068/discussion-between-q-p-and-jimb).